# Why doesn't this simple if : checked input work properly?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an radio input, and on a button elsewhere on the page, I check if it is checked or not and change the value of checked to on or off.

The input looks like:

```
<input type="radio" name="send" value="1"  checked="true" />
```

Or

```
<input type="radio" name="send" value="1"  />
```

I have fairly straightforward jQuery to do the check:

```
$input = $('input[name=send]');

if( $input.is(":checked") ) 
{
    $input.attr("checked", false);
}
else
{
    $input.attr("checked", true);
}
```

The problem is, if the page loads and the input is checked, for some reason I need to click the button twice, before it recognises the else part of the statement.

If the page starts with the input unchecked, then on the first click of the button, it works as expected. And then every click afterwards works. But just not the initial load, if the input is checked.

What is the proper way of marking an input as checked?

How is a proper if / else statement done on a input[type=radio] to see if it is checked?

Comment: `$input.prop('checked',!$input[0].checked);` ?

or better `$input[0].checked = !$input[0].checked`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to access `checked` property of `checkbox` instead of attr, it happened to me for jQuery 1.9, it works for jQuery 1.8.3 but its better to use prop()

```
if( $input.is(":checked") ) 
{
    $input.prop("checked", false);
}
else
{
    $input.prop("checked", true);
}
```

As @Álvaro G. Vicario said you can use `if( $input.prop("checked") )`

Comment: Or even better: `if( $input.prop("checked") )`. The `prop()` method was a great addition.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.prop()` instead:

```
$input.prop("checked", false/true);
```

So in your code:

```
if($input.is(":checked")){
    $input.prop("checked", false);
}else{
    $input.prop("checked", true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`checked` is a property of a checkbox, so use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`.

The presence of the `checked` attribute checks the checkbox, regardless of its value.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely what you want.

```
$input.prop('checked', function(i, oldVal){
    return !oldVal;
});
```

You're dealing with two radio buttons...so this will work.